# Range Won't Define

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, if-statement, range

Can someone help me understand why the last line doesn't run?

What I'm trying to accomplish:

Define a range that that starts with the line under the cell that contains "Added Info/Options" and ends with the last cell that contains a value in the previous column. The cell that contains "Added Info/Options" is variable.

[Sample Cells to Understand Range to be Defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfryZ.png)

So the Range would be rows i+1 to i+etc in column 5 in above picture

Thanks <3

```
Dim KeyCells As Range
Dim i, j, iRow, a, b As Integer
    For i = 1 To 500 Step 1
    If Not Cells(i, 5).Value = "Added Info/Options" Then
        Exit Sub
    Else:
        a = i + 1
        For iRow = a To i + 20 Step 1
            If Len(Cells(iRow, 4)) > 0 Then
                j = i + iRow
            End If
        Next iRow
    End If
    Next i
    KeyCells = Range(Cells(a, 6), Cells(j, 6))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim f As Range, KeyCells As Range

With ActiveSheet

    Set f = .Rows(5).Find(What:="Added Info/Options", lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then
        Set f = f.Offset(1, -1)
        Set KeyCells = .Range(f, .Cells(.Rows.Count, f.Column).End(xlUp))
    Else
        Msgbox "Required header not found!"
    End If

End With
```

Comment: Thanks! This was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Loops are slow. Match is fast and the last populated cell can be easily located looking from the bottom up.

```
dim aio as variant, keyCells As Range

with worksheets("sheet1")
    aio = application.match("Added Info/Options", .columns(5), 0)
    if not iserror(aio) then
        set keyCells = .range(.cells(aio+1, "E"), .cells(.rows.count, "D").end(xlup).offset(0, 1))
    else
        debug.print "Added Info/Options not found"
    end if
end with
```

Comment: Thanks! This was very helpful